# Using not in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am new in python and need help with short code snippet below:

```
x=5 
print(not x<=6)
```

Why the result is False? I think in the next way: not x is False, 0. Then 0 is less than 6. It's True.

Comment: How about thinking in this way: x<=6 is True; not True is False. ?

Comment: First the mathematical expression will be evaluated , i.e, x<=6 , and then the operator . Here, x<=6 is True . Therefore , negation (not) of True is False.

Comment: @Austin I think code must be like that: not(x<=6). But in my variant it is: not x. This causes me problem.

Comment: The 'not' is a Logical operator in Python that will return True if the expression is False. Just like the "!" in java.

In your case, x<=6 is True, "not" operator will reverse the result so it will return False.

Answer (score 0):

You have set x equal to 5. This means that when you logically check if x is less than or equal to 6, it will be True. Since you have not there, it cancels the True to make it False, therefore printing False.

I think you may have got your operator precedence mixed up:

**<, <=, >, >=, !=, ==** all take precedence over **not**